# unable to upload images in the folder while using ajax

Tags: ajax, image, file-upload, ctrl

I am supposed to upload images using using **Ctrl keys** for which I am using Ajax, but the problem is that while uploading the image names in the database successfully I am not able to upload them in the folder under the name **images**

I have the following code which is able to upload my images using ajax on database but **unable to upload images in the folder**

```
<script>
    function showChar(e){
        if(e.ctrlKey && e.charCode == 98){
            e.preventDefault();

            var j = $('#fl').click();
            if(j){saveImage();}

        }
    }

    function saveImage(){

        //var abc = $('#form1').serialize();
        //alert(abc);return false;

        var fl = $('#fl').val();                        
        if(fl != ''){
            alert('t');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'sent.php',
                data: 'fl='+fl,
                success:function(msg){

                }
            }); 

            //$.ajaxFileUpload();           

        }
    }   

</script>
</head>
<body onkeypress="showChar(event);">

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="form1">
    <input type="file" name="fl" id="fl" value=""/>
    <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" onclick="saveImage();"/>
</form>
```

and the query as

```
$fl = $_REQUEST['fl'];
    $name = $_FILES['fl']['name'];
    $temp = $_FILES['fl']['tmp_name'];


    move_uploaded_file($temp, 'images/'.$fl);

    $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_browse (fld_name) VALUES ('$fl')";    
    $res = mysql_query($query);

    if(mysql_num_rows($res)>0){ return 'U'; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24839628/1640577
check question and answer

```
           $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'sent.php',
                data: 'fl='+fl,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false , 
                success:function(msg){

                }
            });
```