# Set AJAX Content Type with plain JavaScript (No JQuery)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html, content-type

I'm working on form submission with AJAX but using plain JavaScript, no external libraries.

I've been having a problem when it comes to parsing the form as the PHP doesn't seem to be parsing the data correctly.

From some research on the internet, I've seen people set the content type to "false". The problem is however, they are are using JQuery to do this and I'm not sure how I do this in plain JavaScript.

I am only submitting a file and my PHP processes forms uploaded the traditional way perfectly.
The AJAX also seems to work flawlessly and I see no fault in the code. Here is my upload function.

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("upload-file", document.getElementById('upload-file').files[0]);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

/* I add some event listeners here for progress, load, error, and abort */

xhr.open("POST", "upload.php");
xhr.send(fd);
```

Comment: What content type do you need to set? And what page was suggesting that?

Comment: It was another question on here actually I found. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24839009/php-doesnt-parse-data-from-multipart-form-data-forms-data-sent-by-ajax

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Setting_HTTP_request_headers

Comment: The way to set the content type has been told you. But I have a feeling that was a workaround for jQuery. In your case, you need to do some debug to understand where the error is. With a network monitor (e.g. Chrome's Inspector window), can you see if the file is actually being uploaded?

Comment: I used the network tab in Firefox and from what I can see, it is uploading. It sends data of the correct size to upload.php.

Comment: Ok, so now point the AJAX form to a dummy PHP page containing: `<?php var_dump($_POST, $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], file_get_contents('php://input')) ?>`. What's the result? PS: you need to tag me in comments, by writing @ + Qualcuno

Comment: It turned out to be an ID/name mismatch. Being new to the area of file uploading and AJAX, I overlooked the name attribute of $_FILES in my PHP. Thank you very much for your help though! @Qualcuno

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to set the content type you need to modify the request header.

I don't know which content type you'd like to set, so I've defaulted to json.

Here's how you can set it:

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("upload-file", document.getElementById('upload-file').files[0]);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

/* I add some event listeners here for progress, load, error, and abort */

xhr.open("POST", "upload.php");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");
xhr.send(fd);
```

**EDIT:** [Setting HTTP request headers from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Setting_HTTP_request_headers)

Comment: *You must call setRequestHeader() after open(), but before send().* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#setRequestHeader()

Comment: Thank you for the code and also where to put it! I've set it to image/jpeg as the image I am trying to upload is a jpeg. (I detect this in JavaScript, it should support various files)

It doesn't seem to have solved my problem of the PHP parsing however. Any idea what content type I need for AJAX forms?

Comment: Yep!  I didn't notice, but when you're uploading files via AJAX, you need to set the content type to be the same as if you were uploading it via a PHP form.  Set it to `multipart/form-data` and let me know how that goes.

Comment: I set it as multipart/form-data yet still no luck although it is different.

Before I modified content-type, when I requested $_FILES["file"]["name"] it was blank, but now it gives "0"

Comment: You shouldn't be able to access the file using `$_FILES['file']`  Since you're appending `upload-file` to the `FormData`, try accessing it with `$_FILES['upload-file']` instead.

Comment: I feel very silly but you're completely right... I had an id/name mismatch. That works and my AJAX form works perfectly now. I'm new to the whole area of AJAX and file uploading in general so I assumed there was a problem with some of my code.

Thank you very much for all the help!